# percentage in jquery css Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why the JQuery syntax below is not correct:

```
 $('#Footer').css({ right: 6%, bottom: 0 });
```

And this one is:

```
 $('#Footer').css('right', '6%');
 $('#Footer').css('bottom', '0');
```

What is incorrect in the first code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try with this {right: '6%'} in first. because your not passing int there. SO, you need to add '6%'..

Comment: It's already been fixed in most of the answers, but `botton` should be `bottom`.

Comment: Man, this syntax is not even correct Javascript, so don't write "correct jQuery syntax"...

Comment: La-comadreja why did you reverted the edit? There is no such thing as "jQuery syntax", it's all Javascript. When will you people understand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`6%` is not a number, so it must be specified as a string.

```
$('#Footer').css({ right: '6%', bottom: 0 });
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `''`

```
$('#Footer').css({ right: '6%', bottom: '0' });
```

for reference http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

Answer (score 0):

because of your missing quotes

it should be

```
 $('#Footer').css({ 'right': '6%', 'bottom': 0 });
```

Comment: For property names, the quotes are in fact optional.

Answer (score -1):

> `$('#Footer').css({ 'right': '6%', 'bottom': 0 });`

Is the right answer as Kimtho6 stated.

Kapa is universally mistaken in this instance. As the quotes are only optional when using single word properties; if you used his reasoning then your code would fail when getting the `padding-right` property.

It's the same reason JSON requires quotes. Because quotes make property names universal. And because that's how JS and many other coding languages do not allow the `-` character as standalone property names; because it was a math symbol before there was any computer coding languages.

**Fail:**

`$('#Footer').css({ padding-top: '6%', padding-bottom: 0 });`

**Success:**

`$('#Footer').css({ 'padding-top': '6%', 'padding-bottom': 0 });`

Comment: You are universally mistaken, because if you write `56vw` instead of `0` your code will fail :).